# Problem with translating Divi inside wordpress

Tags: wordpress, translation, divi

I got a problem regarding translating DIVI into other languages.

There are 4 labels that does not get translated:

- Read more
- X comments
- Submit a comment
- Submit comment

The strings stay in English, even though the site is defined to work in Spanish.

Many strings of the theme do get translated, but these don't. To achieve that, I have installed the LOCO plugin.

After I have installed LOCO, I have uploaded their PO file (that has been [downloaded from their site](https://help.elegantthemes.com/en/articles/2434045-how-to-translate-the-divi-theme)), and then tried to sync it with the theme’s files, to create a template.

As a result, I got only 32 strings, that are available for translation, which is different from the 800 strings, that came with the PO file.

Any idea what can I do to make DIVI get exposed to LOCO?
Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Answer have been given in wordpress support forums:

> Tim W (@timwhitlock):
>
> Creating a template extracts strings from source code; it does not sync from a another PO file.
> This is probably why you get only 32 strings.
>
> If you want to translate the 800 strings in their PO file, use the
> Copy function. See the guide: [How to customize existing
> translations](https://localise.biz/wordpress/plugin/custom-translations)
>
> Alternatively set a PO file as the configured template in the [bundle
> configuration](https://localise.biz/wordpress/plugin/manual/bundle-config).

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/problem-with-translating-divi/